# Google Drive duplicated a file tens of thousands of times and now stuck syncing

Tags: google-drive

my google drive app starting bogging down and my files weren't syncing from the desktop app to the online google drive. Now my app is stuck syncing 17,000 files (that I didn't create or duplicate). Help.

Comment: i've been trying to do that. It's tedious trying to delete 17000 + files. I just need to know how or why google drive duplicated a file 17000 + times. I didn't do it.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info. Have you just installed it? Give us an example of some of the file names and properties.

Comment: no, not just installed. A few years now, for work.... there are 7 of us. The file was a jpeg photo that belonged with a story in a folder. The story and folder are 2 years old. I noticed the google drive icon (desktop) was spinning out a couple of weeks ago and opened the info window. That's where I saw the unending list of the same file. Did a little more exploring and according to google drive, I was duplicating that jpeg up to 300 times a day since some time in February. Which I was not doing. Nor was anyone else who works here. (just the one jpeg is involved in this)

Comment: "tedious trying to delete 17000 + files"? If Ctrl-A is not working for you, install any file management tool that lets you make more detailed selections (recommendation: Total Commander), then delete (*not* to waste bin)

Comment: A quick search for "google drive duplicating" shows a lof ot hits, notably https://support.google.com/drive/thread/229976999/drive-is-duplicating-my-files-and-folders-suddenly?hl=en  According to many of those first thing to do is "remove uploaded items from the source folder" anyway

Comment: nothing works. I've tried everything I found. If I find a way I'll post a message. Thanks anyway. (also, There was no option to 'delete', only to 'bin') By the way.... if I tried to delete too many at once it would crash. (thanks for the ctrl A..... but of course I knew that.... who doesn't?) Have a good day

Comment: What would crash?

Comment: *"there are 7 of us"* disconnecting and cleaning up seems like the normal path. Sounds like you may have an issue on your PC that could benefit from co-located IT support.  Eyes on the problem is useful and an advantage we don't have from here.

Comment: *"**nothing** works. I've tried **everything** I found."* This type of information isn't helpful. We need to know specifically what **nothing** is and what **everything**  is to be of help to you with your problem.